# ¿Cómo hacer para que un botón, solo despliegue un collapse, y no lo comprima?

Tags: html, bootstrap

Tengo una serie de Collapsible de Bootstrap, y quiero que el botón de + únicamente despliegue el Collapsible, que es cuando se va a insertar, no que al darle click se cierre si ya esta abierto.

[image: El botón "Email" despliega y comprime el Collapse, eso está bien. Pero quiero que el botón + solo lo despliegue, y si está abierto no haga nada.]

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<div class="form-group row text-center">
        <button class="btn col-11" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#cPago" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="cPago">
            Comportamientos pago <span class="badge badge-light text-dark">{{cPago.length}}</span>
        </button>
        <i class="fas fa-plus text-success col-1" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#cPago" (click)="cPago.push('')" [hidden]="btnStatus"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse col-11" id="cPago">
        <div class="card card-body block-center">
            <table class="table">
                <tr *ngFor="let c of cPago, let i = index trackBy:trackByFn">
                    <td class="col-10"><input type="number" class="form-control"
                        [(ngModel)]="cPago[i]" [disabled]="inputStatus" required
                        maxlength="3" name="in3"></td>
                    <td class="col-1"><i class="far fa-trash-alt text-danger"
                        (click)="cPago.splice(i,1)" [hidden]="btnStatus"></i></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vas a tener que usar jQuery y el evento `shown.bs.collapse` de boostrap.  Te dejo un ejemplo.

```js
$('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function (e) {
  $('.btn.col-11').prop("disabled",true);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group row text-center">
        <button class="btn col-11" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#cPago" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="cPago">
            Comportamientos pago <span class="badge badge-light text-dark">{{cPago.length}}</span>
        </button>
        <i class="fas fa-plus text-success col-1" data-toggle="collapse"
            data-target="#cPago" (click)="cPago.push('')" [hidden]="btnStatus"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse col-11" id="cPago">
        <div class="card card-body block-center">
            <table class="table">
                <tr *ngFor="let c of cPago, let i = index trackBy:trackByFn">
                    <td class="col-10"><input type="number" class="form-control"
                        [(ngModel)]="cPago[i]" [disabled]="inputStatus" required
                        maxlength="3" name="in3"></td>
                    <td class="col-1"><i class="far fa-trash-alt text-danger"
                        (click)="cPago.splice(i,1)" [hidden]="btnStatus"></i></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Estoy usando angular6, ¿Cómo podría usar JQuery desde Typescript?

Comment: Encontre ese link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32050645/how-to-use-jquery-with-typescript

Comment: No tengo acceso a github, por lo tanto no puedo descargar este tipo de paquetes.

No conoces otra forma de hacerlo, sin usar JQuery?

Comment: debes usar [bootstrap para angular](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap) y no tendras problemas